# 7x6 Grid Anagrams #1

Tags: wordplay, anagram

Solve out these 6 letter anagrams and fit them into a 7x6 grid such that the first and last column read out name of a famous author.

```
IABCUL

RBHKEO

RGIEAH

LIABEL

ELDWEC

ETMNEI

OASUJS
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to the anagrams in order is clearly:

> clewed
>  hegari
>  abulic
>  rhebok
>  liable
>  emetin
>  sajous

And the famous author is:

> Charles Dickens

Comment: I have heard of exactly one of these words before. The rest are incredibly obscure.

Comment: @Deusovi Hey, words are words :)